# In an A5/1 stream cipher, why do the registers have a stepping probability of 3/4

Tags: encryption

I know that the probability of each register to step is 3/4 but I have yet to find an explanation of why. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look at from a bit perspective. The only thing that A5/1 is dependent on, as far as stepping, is the maj(x,y,z) function. X,Y,Z can only take on 0 or 1, respectively. Thus, a three bit representation can be seen as follows:
xyz
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

You can see that for every register the probability that only one register will be in the majority will happen in 6 out of 8 of the cases, as shown above. Where 6/8 = 3/4 = %75. From here you can easily determine the different probabilities where an N number of registers will be in the majority.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is the correct answer. Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 1):

In [A5/1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/1), there are three shift registers (about 20 bits each), each with a certain bit (about in the middle) controlling clocking. At each cycle, a register is shifted when its clock bit agrees with one or both of the other two clock bits.

Under the fair approximation that the clock bits are random, independent, and evenly distributed, a given register is thus shifted with odds $3\over4$ (derivation: as the odds of a coin toss matching either of two other coin tosses).

Answer (score 0):

I was also pondering this question and I don't much like fgrieu's answer so therefore, I will do my best to answer this.

Given that P(A and B) = P(A) x P(B) and the P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) for independent mutually exclusive events and also that each shift register is only clocked if it is the majority.

We can do this:

- P(A random bit is 1) = 1/2
- P(Two bits are 1) = (1/2) * (1/2) = 1/4
- P(All bits are 1) = (1/2) * (1/2) * (1/2) = 1/8
- P(1 is the majority) = 3/8
- P(Two bits are 0) = 1/4
- P(All bits are 0) = 1/8
- P(0 is the majority) = 3/8

Thus the probability that 1 register will be in the majority = P(the clock register will be in the 1 majority or the 0 majority) = P(0 is the majority) + P(1 is the majority) = (3/8) + (3/8) = (3/4)

Comment: If your $P(A~or~B)$ is $P(A \cup B)$, then $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent this gives $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$ in general. How do you justify the claim that $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$?

Comment: Ahh yes nice catch, this only applies for mutually exclusive events, but in the case of A5/1 the P(A or B) is mutually exclusive since P(1 being the majority) cannot happen at the same time as P(0 being in the majority).